# Generating findBugs report in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, findbugs

I have to run the findBugs from Jenkins and generate the report to a specific file. I am looking for detailed steps to do this.

I have added the plugin in Jenkins and have the below in the pom.xml

```
enter code here

<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>findbug</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <effort>Max</effort>
                <threshold>Low</threshold>
                <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                    ${project.build.directory}/findbugs
                </findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
                <failOnError>false</failOnError>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>transform</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <transformationSets>
                    <transformationSet>
                        <dir>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</dir>
                        <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</outputDir>
                        <stylesheet>fancy-hist.xsl</stylesheet>
                        <fileMappers>
                            <fileMapper
                                implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FileExtensionMapper">
                                <targetExtension>.html</targetExtension>
                            </fileMapper>
                        </fileMappers>
                    </transformationSet>
                </transformationSets>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>findbugs</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>failing-on-high</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>findbugs</goal>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <effort>Max</effort>
                        <threshold>Low</threshold>
                        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How to run findBugs and generate report?

Answer (score 0):

You need this in the findbugs-maven-plugin configuration section:

```
          <findbugsXmlOutput>true</findbugsXmlOutput>
          <findbugsXmlWithMessages>true</findbugsXmlWithMessages>
          <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
```

Also, you need to run the maven goal findbugs:findbugs.  You can find details in the "How to Use" section of the plugin description page here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FindBugs+Plugin

Comment: Is there a way to generate visual report in Jenkins ?

Comment: @OnePlus did you get this to work and if so, did you specify the location fo the findbugs xml file in jenkins?